# Problem drawing "frames" in a UIView with Core Graphics using C# in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, core-graphics

Within a `UIView` in a Xamarin.iOS project I have an event the regularly fires and calls `SetNeedsDisplay()` whenever the contents of that view needs to be redrawn:

```
delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetNeedsDisplay();
};
```

I also have some Core Graphics calls within the overriden `Draw()` method of the `UIView`, representative as such:

```
public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
{
    base.Draw(rect);
    using (var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
    {
        // Draw a rectangle of a variable width and height
        context.FillRect(new CGRect(0, 0, _width, _height));
    }
}
```

Drive by the event described above, `SetNeedsDisplay()` is called 2-3 times per second.  With different values for `_width` and `_height`, I would expect the rectangle to be rapidly drawn with different sizes on the screen, as often as `SetNeedsDisplay()` is called.  However, the rectangle is only redrawn once or twice *per minute*.

**How can I draw with Core Graphics at the frequency I desire?**

Answer (score 0):

`SetNeedsDisplay()` must be called from the **main thread** in order to have its desired effect.  The event above is not running on the main thread, therefore the call to `SetNeedsDisplay()` needs to be invoked as follows:

```
InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    SetNeedsDisplay();
});
```